# what does Direct effect significance and non-significance means in mediation

Tags: mediation

There are 4 conditions for the significance of mediation:

1. Significance of (X → Y),
2. Significance of(X → M)
3. Significance of(M|X → Y) ,
4. **Insignificance** of (X|M → Y).

**Does it mean partial mediation, or that "it may or may not be a complete mediation"?**
**Secondly if the 4th condition isn't met & is significant also, then what the whole scenario?**

Answer (score 1):

1) Condition 1. has been critized since it may happen that you have a direct and an indirect effect cancelling out (MacKinnon et al., 2000).

2) Condition 2. & 3. are definitely required for mediation.

3) Condition 4. is required for **complete mediation** (Judd and Kenny, 1981).  If this condition is not met but 2. & 3. are, you have **partial mediation** (Baron and Kenny, 1986).

Baron RM, Kenny DA. The moderator–mediator variable distinction in social psychological research: Conceptual, strategic, and statistical considerations. Journal of Personality and Social Psychology 1986;51:1173–1182.

Judd CM, Kenny DA. Process analysis: Estimating mediation in treatment evaluations. Evaluation Review 1981;5:602–619.

MacKinnon DP, Krull JL, Lockwood CM. Equivalence of the mediation, confounding, and suppression effect. Prevention Science 2000;1:173–181.